# What is the significance of Fermi temperature?

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature, fermi-energy

The Fermi temperature of a solid is related to Fermi energy by relation
$$
{ E }_{ F } ={ k }_{ B }\times{ T }_{ F }
$$
where $ { k }_{ B } $ is Boltzmann constant.
But what is the significance of Fermi temperature?

Comment: "The Fermi temperature can be thought of as the temperature at which thermal effects are comparable to quantum effects associated with Fermi statistics". Source: [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy) on the Fermi Energy. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi, I am guessing you have already read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient research effort.

Comment: It is related to Boltzmann condensate and quantum energy levels described in detail in A. Einensteinum's theory of photoelectric effect. For which he was nominated to the Newborn prize.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to decide whether a gas of fermions is degenerate$^*$, then you would compare the temperature of the gas with its Fermi temperature.  If $T \ll T_F$ then the gas can be considered completely degenerate. If $T \sim T_F$ then the gas is partially degenerate. If $T > T_F$ then the gas is not degenerate.

If the fermion gas is degenerate then the average kinetic energy of the fermions is $3k_B T_F/5$ (if they are non-relativistic; if they are relativistic then their average energy is $3k_B T_F/4$).

$^*$ By degenerate, I mean that the occupation index for the available quantum states has the characteristic form of a degenerate gas - equal to unity for states with $E< k_B T_F$ and zero for $E>k_B T_F$.

Comment: What does it mean for a fermi gas to be degenerate?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the meanings already discussed, the Fermi temperature can also be thought of as the order of temperature at which a classical gas would have the same energy as a Fermi gas at $T=0K$.

The average energy of a Fermi gas of $N$ fermions at $T=0K$ is given by $\langle E \rangle =\frac{3}{5} NE_F$. For an ideal gas, according to the equipartition theorem, $\langle E \rangle =\frac{3}{2} N k T$. Therefore, if the average energies were the same for both gases, the temperature that the ideal gas should have would be

$$
T=\frac{2}{5} \frac{E_F}{k}=\frac{2}{5} T_{F}
$$

Answer (score 0):

When we measure the temperature of a material,  we  do  not  typically  measure  the  temperature  of  a  single  atom  or  electron.  What we measure is the average temperature of the material. There is invariably going to be a distribution of energy within the material. In this distribution, an extremely small thermal mass, consisting of a very small fraction of the nearly free electrons (which is itself a very small fraction of the total electrons in the system), is at the Fermi energy, and the temperature corresponding to that energy is  the  relatively  high  Fermi  temperature.  Therefore  the  **high** Fermi  temperature  is  not inconsistent with the **low** temperature or the solid as a whole.

Reference: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/113106040/Lecture25.pdf