# How can the fermi temperature of a fermi gas tell us about if it is degenerate or not?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, fermions, fermi-energy

I know that If $T≪TF$ then the gas can be considered completely degenerate. If $T∼TF$ then the gas is partially degenerate. If $T>TF$ then the gas is not degenerate. But I don't know how we can tell the degeneracy of a fermion gas by comparing it's temperature with the fermi temperature of that fermion gas.

Comment: Closely linked (duplicate?)  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216207/  I don't understand your question - by comparing the temperature with the Fermi temperature - as you do in your question - tells us whether it is degenerate.

Comment: I don't how can we tell by just comparing I mean fermi temperature is defined as Ef=Tf*K but why this specific temperature tell us anything about degeneracy is not understood by me